# GTK+ CSS for one button

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

How to set color for one button in GTK+

```
GtkButton button8 { 
border-radius: 20;
border-width: 1 1 1 1;
font: Sans 16;
color: black;
background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
             left top,
             left bottom,
             color-stop(0.0,rgba(34,97,170,1)),
             color-stop(0.50,rgba(56,145,218,1)),
             color-stop(0.51,rgba(34,131,216,1)),
             color-stop(1.00,rgba(134,191,234,1)));
}
```

This css changes the color of al buttons in glade file.How should i change the css so that it affects only one button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gtk_widget_set_name (widget, "fooname");` or do the same in glade:

---

[image: mark of are to set the image name]

---

then use something like

```
GtkButton#fooname {
     border-radius: 20;
     ...
}
```

See https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html

Comment: is fooname the Label name

Comment: In glade version 3.14.2 Widget name attribute is missing Which version are you using?

Comment: `# glade --version
glade 3.16.1`

Comment: Where do you put the CSS?