# How to set CSS class for specific button in gtkmm3 in c++ on Linux

Tags: c++, css, linux, gtk, gtkmm3

I'm new in Linux programming.
Recently I've started to learn gtkmm3 to make GUI for my study project, but I stuck on this problem.
I have few buttons, which are styled with CSS file and I want to set other style to selected button, but nothing works.
This is how I make buttons and read CSS file:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv);
Gtk::Window window;
window.set_default_size(800, 480);

Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> cssProvider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
cssProvider->load_from_path("style.css");   
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> styleContext = Gtk::StyleContext::create();
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default();//get default screen
styleContext->add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);//add provider for screen in all application

Gtk::Box *vbox = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Box(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0));
window.add(*vbox); 

Gtk::Button *b1 = new Gtk::Button("b1");
b1->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_b1_click));

Gtk::Button *b2 = new Gtk::Button("b2");
b2->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&on_b1_click));

vbox->add(*b1);
vbox->add(*b2);
```

and CSS file:

```css
.button {
 color: red;
 background: red;
 border-color: red;
}
.button:hover { 
 color: yellow;
    background-color: yellow;
 border-color: yellow;
}
.myButton{
 color: red;
 background: blue;
 border-color: red;
}
```

I tried to set other style for button like this:

```
GtkStyleContext *context;
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (GTK_WIDGET (b1));
gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "myButton");
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609381/how-to-set-a-specific-css-class-to-a-widget-in-gtk3-c), but get error while running app:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from '(null)' to 'GtkWidget'
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_style_context: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_context_add_class: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
```

and

```
gtk_widget_set_name (b1, "myButton");
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012039/gtk-css-for-one-button)
but get compile error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: main.cpp:34:40: error: cannot convert ‘Gtk::Button*’ to ‘GtkWidget* {aka _GtkWidget*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void gtk_widget_set_name(GtkWidget*, const gchar*)’
 gtk_widget_set_name (b1, "myButton");
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing [GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/) with [gtkmm](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.22/) (C++ interface for GTK+). `b1` is not a [GtkButton](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/GtkButton.html) but [Gtk::Button](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.22/classGtk_1_1Button.html).

Use [Gtk::StyleContext](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.22/classGtk_1_1StyleContext.html):

```
Glib::RefPtr<StyleContext> context = b1->get_style_context();
context->add_class("myButton");
```